# I'm trying to mask a date in pandas, before and after

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, mask

I was able to mask before and after the election date-time into a bool, but when I try to print the df, it returns a key error for the mask

```
election= dt.datetime(2021, 11, 8)
maskA = df['created_at'] >= election
maskB = df['created_at'] <= election
df['maskA']
```

Answer (score 0):

You created maskA as a mask indeed. But using df['maskA'] looks for a column named 'maskA'. Try df.loc[maskA] instead. Alternatively, you can combine both like this:

```
df.loc[df['created_at'] >= election]
```

Comment: This returned only the titles of the df, which is weird. I still got a key error when I tried to run the code. here`s the full code:                                                                                 
```maskA= df.loc[df['created_at'] >= election]
maskB= df.loc[df['created_at'] <= election]
df.groupby('maskA')['source'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie')```

Comment: Ah, I see. The .loc does not only create a mask, it directly filters the dataframe with that information. So for your groupby it would be: df.loc[df['created_at'] >= election].groupby('maskA')['source'].value_counts().plot(kind='pie')

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
election= dt.datetime(2021, 11, 8)
maskA = df['created_at'] >= election
maskB = df['created_at'] <= election
df[maskA]
```

It returns a key error for the mask, because when you call `df['maskA']`, you are asking for a column with name `'maskA'` while your intention is to use the object (which is a boolean mask) that you have just created, `maskA`.